# Could not resolve module "tailwindcss/nesting"

Tags: tailwind-css, postcss

While following the [official guide for TailwindCSS with PostCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting) I find myself with the error:

```
@parcel/transformer-postcss: Could not resolve module "tailwindcss/nesting" from "C:\Users\Daniel\source\repos\AFP_Reservas\.postcssrc"
```

My .postcssrc file looks like this:

```
{
    "modules": false,
    "plugins": {
        "postcss-import": {},
        "tailwindcss/nesting": {},
        "tailwindcss": {}
        "autoprefixer": {
            "grid": true
        }
    }
}
```

tailwind.config.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  future: {
    // removeDeprecatedGapUtilities: true,
    // purgeLayersByDefault: true,
  },
  purge: [
    './Maquetas/home.html'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

And I have the following dependencies installed:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "parcel": "^2.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.3.11",
    "postcss-import": "^14.0.2",
    "postcss-nested": "^5.0.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.9.6"
  }
```

Am I missing something? I tried installing @tailwindcss/nesting, but the nesting module is supposed to be a part of the core tailwindcss module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I'm using Tailwind version 1.9 (to support Internet Explorer due to client needs) I can't use tailwindcss/nesting, according to the [1.9 documentation](https://v1.tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting) you have to use `postcss-nested`.